# form view - inserting using my own DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a form view which is inserting data into a sql-server-2008 database. instead of using the formview's functionality of entering data into the database, i would like it to use my own data access layer. since i am a beginner at asp.net i do not understand how to intercept the INSERT and do my own insert. i need to grab text out of the text boxes and process the data myself.

**question**: at which point do i intercept the INSERT (after the user clicks on the INSERT link)? where exactly do i add my own code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RECOMMENDED SOLUTION**

I think you've gone a little beyond the scope of the control if you need to control the actual insert command. At this point, you should move to just handling a button click event and invoke your DAL directly, from such a control as a `<asp:Button/>` and perhaps use another UI control if you are dependent on the `FormView` control to present the UI.

**THE BELOW IS A HACK - Only do as a last resort**

However, you could 'hack' the `FormView` control by attaching to the `ItemInserting` event, and then insert via your DAL. Then you would simply "Cancel" the insert by setting the `Cancel` property to true:

```
void EmployeeFormView_ItemInserting(Object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
     // Do Stuff
     e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering *as well as* recommending a better way.  That hack you pointed out sounds like it would be a pain to debug =).

Comment: @tejs thanks this is very helpful! can you please how me how i would submit with the asp:button please?

Comment: There would be no magic; simply attaching to the click event of the button, and then getting the data from your form controls to determine what would be inserted, and then calling your DAL. It's all going to be *your project specific* code.

Comment: @tejs how would i pass the text from a textbox into a function?

Comment: You access it from the click event. IE; directly (if it is a static control on the page like `textSomething.Text` or by looking it up through the object hierarchy. Like I said, it's going to depend on your code.